# Html Agility Pack: Setting an HtmlNode's Attribute Value isn't reflected in the HtmlDocument

Tags: html-agility-pack, setattribute

In Html Agility Pack, when I set an attribute of an HtmlNode, should I see this in the HtmlDocument from which the node was selected?

Lets say that htmlDocument is an HtmlDocument. So the simplified code looks like this:

```
HtmlNode documentNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode;
HtmlNodeCollection nodeCollection = documentNode.SelectNodes(someXPath);
foreach(var node in nodeCollection)
   if(SomeCondition(node))
       node.SetAttributeValue("class","something");
```

Now, I see the class attribte of node change, but I don't see this change reflected in the htmlDocument's html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it was a case of ProgrammerTooStupidException :(

I used a MyHtmlPage class, with an Html property and an DocumentProperty.

```
_html = theHtml;
_htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
HtmlDocument.LoadHtml(theHtml)l
_documentNode = HtmlDocument.DocumentNode;
```

Now, of coourse manipulation the DocumentNode had no effect on the _html value.

Posting this reply to clear the name of HAP.