# HtmlAgilityPack : How do I combine html elements together into one tag with a class?

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

**Issue:**
I need to examine some HTML elements using HtmlAgilityPack and combine the tag names.
Is it possible to extract each tag, from the parent to the child, replacing it with a span that has a class with a name of “strikeUEmStrong”. Also, the name changes based on the HTML element.

Order of the name of the class does in fact matter, I realized this through trial and error. As long as its able to get all of the elements and combine them together. It is very possible that it will have multiple text nodes with various levels of formatting.

This will affect multiple paragraphs.

For example, if I have this html code:

```
<p>
<strike><u><em><strong>four styles</strong></em></u></strike></p>
```

How do I convert it to this:

```
<p>
<span class="strikeUEmStrong">four styles</span></p>
```

Its possible to have this type of code as well:

```
<p>
    <strike><u><em><strong>four styles</strong></em></u></strike>&nbsp; <strike><u><em>three styles</em></u></strike></p>
<p>
    <em><strong>two styles</strong></em></p>
```

The output should look like this:

```
<p>
<span class="strikeUEmStrong">four styles</span>&nbsp; <span class="strikeUEm">three styles<span></p><p><span class="emStrong">two styles<span></p>
```

**Prototype:**

```
'Retrive the class name of each format node
Function GetClassName(ByVal n As HtmlNode) As String
    Dim ret As String = String.Empty

    If (n.Name <> "#text") And (n.Name <> "p") Then
        ret = n.Name + " "
    End If

    'Get the next node
    For Each child As HtmlNode In n.ChildNodes
        ret &= GetClassName(child)
    Next

    Return ret
End Function

'Create a list of class names
Function GetClassNameList(ByVal classNameList As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim ret As New List(Of String)
    Dim classArr() As String = classNameList.Split(" ")

    For Each className As String In classArr
        ret.Add(className)
    Next

    Return ret
End Function

'Sort a list of class names and return a merged class string
Function GetSortedClassNameString(ByVal classList As List(Of String)) As String

    Dim sortedMergedClass As String = String.Empty

    classList.Sort()

    For Each className As String In classList
        sortedMergedClass &= className
    Next

    Return sortedMergedClass
End Function

'Lets point to the body node
Dim bodyNode As HtmlNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body")

'Lets create some generic nodes
Dim currPNode As HtmlNode

Dim formatNodes As HtmlNodeCollection

Dim text As String = String.Empty
Dim textSize As Integer = 0

'Make sure the editor has something in it
If editorText <> "" Then

   'Send the text from the editor to the body node
    If bodyNode IsNot Nothing Then
       bodyNode.InnerHtml = editorText
    End If

    Dim pNode = bodyNode.SelectNodes("//p")

    Dim span As HtmlNode = htmlDoc.CreateElement("span")
    Dim tmpBody As HtmlNode = htmlDoc.CreateElement("body")
    Dim textNode As HtmlNode = htmlDoc.CreateTextNode

    Dim pCount As Integer = bodyNode.SelectNodes("//body/p").Count - 1

    For childCountP As Integer = 0 To pCount

        Dim paragraph = HtmlNode.CreateNode(htmlDoc.CreateElement("p").WriteTo)

        'Which paragraph I am at.
        currPNode = pNode.Item(childCountP)

        'For this paragraph get me the collection of html nodes
        formatNodes = currPNode.ChildNodes

        'Count how many Format nodes we have in a paragraph
        Dim formatCount As Integer = currPNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1

       'Go through each node and examine the elements. 
       'Then look at the markup to create classes and then group them under one span
       For child As Integer = 0 To formatCount

           'Iterate through the formateNodes, strike, em, strong, etc.
           Dim currFormatNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode(formatNodes(child).WriteTo)

           'TODO: Handle nested images and links? How do we know what to rip out?

           'First check for format nodes
           'Note, we can't let it use everything because it will change nested elements as well. I.E. span within span.
           If (currFormatNode.Name <> "#text") And (currFormatNode.Name = "strike") Or (currFormatNode.Name = "em") _
               Or (currFormatNode.Name = "strong") Or (currFormatNode.Name = "u") Or (currFormatNode.Name = "sub") _
               Or (currFormatNode.Name = "sup") Or (currFormatNode.Name = "b") Then

              'strip all tags, just take the inner text
              span.InnerHtml = currFormatNode.InnerText

              'Create a text node with text from the lowest node
              textNode = htmlDoc.CreateTextNode(span.InnerText)

              'Recursively go through the format nodes
              'Create a list from the string
              'Then sort the list and return a string
              'Appending the class to the span
               span.SetAttributeValue("class", GetSortedClassNameString(GetClassNameList(GetClassName(currFormatNode).Trim())))

              'Attach the span before the current format node
              currFormatNode.ParentNode.InsertBefore(span, currFormatNode)

             'Remove the formatted children leaving the above node
             currFormatNode.ParentNode.ChildNodes.Remove(currFormatNode)

             'We need to build a paragraph here
             paragraph.InnerHtml &= span.OuterHtml

             'Lets output something for debugging
             childNodesTxt.InnerText &= span.OuterHtml

             Else 'handle #text and other nodes seperately
                  'We need to build a paragraph here
                  paragraph.InnerHtml &= span.OuterHtml
                  textNode = htmlDoc.CreateTextNode(currFormatNode.InnerHtml)

                  'Lets output something for debugging
                  childNodesTxt.InnerText &= textNode.OuterHtml
             End If

        Next
        'End of formats

        'Start adding the new paragraph's to the body node
        tmpBody.AppendChild(paragraph)
     Next
     'End of paragraphs

    'Clean out body first and replace with new elements
    htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body").Remove()

    'Update our body
    htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//html").AppendChild(tmpBody)

 End If

 htmlDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("html\editor.html"))
 End If
```

**Output:**

```
<span class="strikeuemstrong">four styles</span>
```

Finally getting the right output, after I fixed the ordering issue. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are you blinding combinging the tag names of all children of P into a single class name?  Or are you intelligently picking?  For example if you swap the order of the string and strong, would the class name still be the same or would it then be StrongUEmStrike  class?

Comment: Its very possible that the items will have multiple text nodes with formatting. depth may very from 1-6 nodes.

Comment: Let me know if I missed a question? I think I gave you everything I know...

Comment: @EliGassert, You were right about the order, I didn't understand the problem well enough, order does in fact matter, at the end I have to provide styles to these classes, but I can't have duplicates. I've suggested a possible solution above, but there might be others.

Comment: And why can't you just use multiple classes? `<span class="strike em u strong">` and a single class for each to add the specific styles?  Seems odd to create composite classes.  You can also query (jquery, [modern] CSS) items that have any combination of classes, e.g. `$('.strike.em')` would find all with both strike and em.  Notice, no space between the class names.  You can do this in CSS too (I think IE7+?  Might be IE8+?  Would have to test).

Comment: @EliGassert, sorry I should have said this, but I didn't want to confuse everyone with the following: this is being formatted this way because it's going to be transformed by XSLT to XML, which will be used in InDesign. InDesign uses styles with properties, so I have to give them solid names. InDesign uses paragraph and character level styles.

Comment: @EliGassert, I was able to fix the order issue with two more functions. Thank you for helping me. Your code tips helped me out big time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a straight forward question to answer.  I'll describe how I'd write the algorithm to do this, and include some pseudo code to help.

1. I'd get my parent tag.  I'll assume you want to do this for all "p" tags
2. I'd iterate over my children tags, taking the tag name and appending it into a class name
3. I'd recursively iterate children until I get my appended tag name

Pseudo-code.  Please excuse any typos, as I'm typing this on the fly.

```
public string GetClassName(Node n)
{
var ret = n.TagName;

foreach(var child in n.ChildNodes)
{
ret += GetClassName(child);
}

return ret;
}


foreach(var p in paragraphs)
{
foreach(var child in p.ChildNodes)
{
 var span = new Span();
 span.InnerText = child.InnerText; // strip all tags, just take the inner text

span.ClassName = GetClassName(child);

child.ReplaceWith(span); // note: if you do this with a FOREACH and not a for loop, it'll blow up C# for modifying the collection while iterating.  Use for loops. if you're going to do "active" replacement like in this pseudo code
}
}
```

I'd be happy to modify my answer once I get more context.  Please review what I'm suggesting and comment on it with more context if you need me to refine my suggestion.  If not, I hope this gets you what you need :)

Comment: In the `foreach(var child in p.ChildNodes)` loop you'll likely want something like `if(child.IsTextNode) continue;` so you don't process those.  I don't have the agility pack DOM reference in front of me, so the collection names and access methods (properties vs methods) are likely wrong, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: I'm going to share what I came up with, but its not working yet, I'm not 100% sure how to use all of the methods yet...

Comment: I'm having trouble with these lines:
span.InnerHtml = child.InnerText
span.Attributes() = GetClassName(child)
child.ReplaceWith(span)

Comment: Attributes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589959/html-agility-pack-setting-an-htmlnodes-attribute-value-isnt-reflected-in-the `span.SetAttributeValue("class", GetClassName(child))`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838282/set-innertext-with-htmlagilitypack According to this, you can only set the text of a text node. `var textNode = htmlDoc.CreateTextNode(child.InnerText)' then 'span.AppendChild(textNode)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011577/html-agility-pack-how-can-append-element-at-the-top-of-head-element instead of replace, you need to do `InsertBefore` (or after) then `child.Parent.RemoveChild(child)`  That should answer the three pieces you had questions with.

Comment: child.InsertBefore(span, child), Node "
 " was not found in the collection
Parameter name: node, also, instead of class I'm getting an integer value.

Comment: `+=` operator in VB is used for numbers.  I think in VB it's `&=`  So that should fi the class name.  As for InsertBefore, it needs to work like the RemoveChild: `child.Parent.InsertBefore(span, child)`

Comment: And again, a for each loop with active modification of the document will not work.  You'll want to use two nested `for` loops instead of `for each`. `foreach` is fine within your `GetClassName` method.

Comment: `removeChild` removes the reference of the parent node, it creates issues for me later, unless I can create my span some how to point to the original parent.

Comment: Before removing, insert your new span before the node you're about to remove. You need to know where inside parent to add a node, not just the original parent. That's why I was using a replace instead of a remove and insert separately

Comment: Actually, that's part is okay, but the issue is when doing that, the span itself does not reference the original html document, its as if its a different html document, so when I look at the parent, its not there. I use `iNode.ParentNode.InsertBeore(span, iNode)` then `iNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(iNode)` The span I created has a different parent, even before I do insertBefore, once I do removeChild, my second run gets messed up because the parents are different.

Comment: Should I use replace child instead of insertBefore?